# Which Ruby on Rails admin plugin do you use and why? What are the pros and cons of different admin gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

We need a dead simple, but secure, admin plugin for Rails. We're on 2.x but are considering a port to 3.x.

Which admin plugin do you use, and why? What are the pros and cons of others? There are a few admin plugins available, and we would like to draw on the experience of others before choosing one.

And by admin plugin, I mean a plugin to help us manage the data and users of the application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is currently the most popular one: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

It's a Rails engine rather than a plugin, but it's good looking and useful.

Comment: Does this override some of your custom models?

Comment: It doesn't like it will, as there are options you can give to the generator and modify its defaults. As usual, if you're integrating into an existing codebase, branch with git, install it, configure, etc. and if it clobbers your code, delete the branch.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at it briefly and it seems like you need to pass it options to run your own model validations...

Comment: Nowadays, [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) seems more popular than [Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin).

Answer (score 8):

Aren't you better off using `Devise` and `CanCan` to create your own admin? Sure, it'll take some work, but you will have full control over your admin/cms and Devise is known to offer authentication across the entire MVC stack.

Most of the approaches I've seen tend to namespace the admin area in particular.

Comment: I second this. It's clean and powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Try Typus 
https://github.com/fesplugas/typus

It uses own authentication/authorization, here are demo: http://demo.typuscms.com/admin

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/). There's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you search under railscasts AND authentication.  There you will find (via Ryan Bates) everything from the super simple "episode 21" to the ones mentioned above.

If you devote 1 hour to watching the 12 podcasts that come from this search, you will better be able to come up with a solution which is appropriate for your needs (based on the great feedback from this community).

Good luck and let us know which one you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Many (me included) prefer not to use a gem for authentication because it is too high a feature for an app; it is sometimes better to code your own for your suited use case.

Now you could go and use devise, authlogic etc., but to me authentication is so important, and if I don't fully understand what is going behind these gems I tend to stay away (depending on the app I am building).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use an "admin" plugin perse.  I use the [declarative_authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) gem.

Pros:

- you get more than just admin/normal user privileges, you get the ability to define your own user roles and explicitly define who can do what
- you get a lot of helper methods for defining certain actions that only certain users can do
- its very popular, very well documented, and very well supported

Cons:

- takes a little bit more to setup

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin is the best and it will customize easily.
Look at this link [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html)